# Ubuntu 14.04 was installed on wrong drive

Tags: dual-boot

Windows Vista is on my C: dive. while installing Ubuntu, somehow it installed on my other drive which is D:
When I start the PC it does not recognize the D: drive after I am in Windows. Just shows C: drive not the D;dive.
So how do I make windows recognize the D: drive or how do I delete Ubuntu on the D: drive?
I can get into Ubuntu and once I am there it does recognize the C: drive.
thank you,
roscoe

Comment: Which drive did you want to install Ubuntu? If you install it on C: drive, it will delete Windows and all your data. Then you will not be able to boot Windows. All your files in C: will be gone too.

Answer (score 0):

Windows doesn't read `ext4` filesystem unless you use dedicated software like [Ext2fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com).

To delete Ubuntu:

1. Boot from windows DVD and select repair. Choose your installation.
2. Select other to open command prompt and type `bootsect.exe /fixmbr` and `bootsect.exe /fixboot`
3. Restart PC. It should boot into Windows
4. Right click my computer, select manage then go to `Disk Management`. Format your second drive as NTFS and assign it letter D.

Answer (score 0):

**When I start the PC it does not recognize the D: drive after I am in Windows. Just shows C: drive not the D;**

Since you can boot into windows...it means your windows is safe and just your D: drive is messed up. Just format the other drive with ntfs file system. Your D: drive will show up again as normal.

**I can get into Ubuntu and once I am there it does recognize the C: drive.**

Ubuntu recognizes ntfs file system as well.